# Webservices & FBA login in VBA

Tags: web-services, vba

I'm trying to call some webservices from an ERP solution; but this solution only allows VBA code. The SharePoint web is secured via FBA, so I need to call authentication.asmx first and then pass the cookie to the other calls I make. The problem is that I don't know how to get the cookie in VBA and how to pass it along. Is this even possible?

As another solution, I though about extending the entire web application to a second site with normal Windows authentication, since that's a bit easier to handle in VBA. But when possible, I'd rather stick with the FBA site. Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Why can't you set up anonymous access on the SharePoint Web Service you intend to access?

Comment: How are you accessing the webservice in your code?  This thread may give you some ideas: http://objectmix.com/xml-soap/86831-excel-vba-xmthttp-cookies.html

Comment: @Free Styler: your solution for security is just not using it? I need security to keep people out of my system.

Comment: @Tim Williams: thanks, very helpful. You can post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140268%28v=office.10%29.aspx) of Microsoft. This tool works in office 2003, in my case i use access 2003 at machine and run this. After i export this module and import to my office version.

This tool create all code needs to work you webservice.

Microsoft could updtate to office 2007/2010!

[]'s